# How to load a contact form inside a lightbox(jquery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What jQuery plugin should i use to load a contact form inside a lightbox?

I found alot of things on google... but i would like to know the most recent thing to do it.

thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "loading a contact"

Comment: I mean: how to load a outfile with a contact form inside a jquery lightbox

Answer (score 5):

Use Fancybox:
http://fancybox.net/

It has iframe support.
Make a page in html with your contact form. Then call it as an iframe with Fancybox!

Include the fanycbox css and js files, then call it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.fancyframe").fancybox({
        'type'   : iframe,
    });

});
```

`<a class="fancyframe" href="contactform.html">Click me to open contact form in Fancybox</a>`

Comment: If I solved your problem. Please consider hitting the checkmark/ I'm trying to get some reputation here to start a bounty fro a major problem on my site. ;)

Comment: where can i find a min version of fancybox?

Comment: jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack = 15kb, it's min version?

Comment: Yeah, (sorry for late response, better late then never!) but Fancybox is a big big. You could try packing it THEN minifying, removing images to support IE or use a sniffer. But to get it down smaller you'll have to work a bit at it.